# Javascript generate transparent 1X1 pixel in dataURL format

Tags: javascript, image-processing, png, base64, pixel

I would like to know a way to generate a single pixel in JavaScript converting it to base64. The ideal function would be:

```
function createPixel(hexColor, opacity){
   //...Calculate
   return base64DataURL;
}
```

I am not very familiar with image processing. Any format is fine (png, gif etc). I would like to use this to overlay background images, (yes I could use rgba css3 but I am trying to place it with a background-image only on one element so i am not overlaying an element on top of another to achieve the effect).

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I would like not to use canvas, I am sure you can use canvas to get the base64 dataURL but I am sure it is not as fast as a string manipulation. Also I am not worried about converting an image into base64 but more interested in creating the image.

Comment: Honestly, using canvas+toDataURL is likely the easiest solution. Otherwise, you're basically going to have to figure out how a 1x1 image of a given color and opacity is represented in whatever format (say, PNG) and then either use a JavaScript base64 encoder on that information, or figure out the pattern and shortcut the external encoding yourself. Is that really worth it?

Comment: You might also find that using `<canvas>` is actually faster than a JavaScript base64 encoder.

Comment: Thanks I guess I will stick with canvas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a fully cross-browser-compatible implementation using `<canvas>` ([demo @ jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/xgLkp/)).

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

// http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/wiki/Instructions#Dynamically_created_elements
if (!canvas.getContext) G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = 1;
canvas.height = 1;

// for simplicity, assume the input is in rgba format
function createPixel(r, g, b, a) {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(' + [r,g,b,a].join() + ')';
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,1,1);
    // 'data:image/png;base64,'.length => 22
    return canvas.toDataURL('image/png','').substring(22);
}
```

I was curious to see how this stacks up against [icktoofay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5845238/javascript-generate-transparent-1x1-pixel-in-dataurl-format/5845511#5845511), performance-wise. Note, this will have to use [excanvas](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/) for IE <9, which means that performance will almost certainly be worse there (but what's new).

Check out the jsperf: http://jsperf.com/base64image

Comment: I optimized my answer a little more so it's not creating functions and lookup tables every time. It would be interesting to see how the optimized one stands up to `canvas`, as well.

Comment: And, apparently, there's a native Base64 encoder in some browsers (`window.btoa`), so I just added that, too.

Comment: Ok great, I updated the jsperf. I did call your function correctly, right? Your optimized version (using native `btoa` when present) blows the other 2 out of the water.

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense. Concatenating a few strings together and then Base64 encoding it is going to be a lot faster than creating a canvas, rendering into it, encoding it as a PNG, and then encoding it into Base64. Regardless, my JavaScript native version is fairly useless; PAM is a very rare format, and is unlikely to be of use to many people.

Answer (score 10):

4+ years later, here's a simpler solution that generates a standard GIF so actually works in browsers (I couldn't get the PEM solution to work in *anything*) and is up to an order of magnitude faster than PEM/canvas. Only downside is GIF doesn't support alpha opacity - but that can be controlled via CSS.

It's based on [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LPxrT/) (unknown beautiful author), but with basic optimisation - reused keyStr and accepts both hex string ('#FF0000') and hex literal (0xFF0000) - latter much faster (thanks *icktoofay*).

```html
<html>

<body onload="Test()">
  <script>
    function Test() {
      var img = new Image;
      img.src = createPixelGIF(0xff0000); // generate a red pixel data URI
      img.height = 100;
      img.width = 100; // optional: add dimensions
      document.body.appendChild(img); // add to the page
    }

    // ROUTINES =============

    var createPixelGIF = (function() {

      var keyStr = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";

      return function createPixelGIF(hexColor) {
        return "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAPAA" + encodeHex(hexColor) + "/yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==";
      }

      function encodeHex(hexColor) {
        var rgb;
        if (typeof hexColor == 'string') {
          var s = hexColor.substring(1, 7);
          if (s.length < 6) s = s[0] + s[0] + s[1] + s[1] + s[2] + s[2];
          rgb = [parseInt(s[0] + s[1], 16), parseInt(s[2] + s[3], 16), parseInt(s[4] + s[5], 16)];
        } else
          rgb = [(hexColor & (0xFF << 16)) >> 16, (hexColor & (0xFF << 8)) >> 8, hexColor & 0xFF];

        return encodeRGB(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]);
      }

      function encodeRGB(r, g, b) {
        return encode_triplet(0, r, g) + encode_triplet(b, 255, 255);
      }

      function encode_triplet(e1, e2, e3) {
        enc1 = e1 >> 2;
        enc2 = ((e1 & 3) << 4) | (e2 >> 4);
        enc3 = ((e2 & 15) << 2) | (e3 >> 6);
        enc4 = e3 & 63;
        return keyStr.charAt(enc1) + keyStr.charAt(enc2) + keyStr.charAt(enc3) + keyStr.charAt(enc4);
      }

    })();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Updated JSPerf results: http://jsperf.com/base64image/4 (code above is "createPixelGIF2"). You'll see I tried further optimisation (3+4), but it seems JS is happier with stack operations than hard-to-read combo functions :)

I also added an updated test for the canvas method, which for some reason excluded the instantiation of the canvas object - the biggest performance drag that would be seen in real world use.

Answer (score 4):

```
function createPlaceholder(w, h) {
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.setAttribute('style', 'width:'+w+'px;height:'+h+'px;border:none;display:block');
    img.src = 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==';
    return img;
}
```

(for transparent pixel)

Answer (score 2):

Try this. It uses a somewhat esoteric image format ([PAM](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pam.html)), but you said any format is fine, and it really does work! It's not optimized or anything, so it's probably pretty slow, but hey, it works.

**Edit:** Okay, I optimized it a little...

```
var createPixel=(function() {
    var table=[];
    for(var i=0;i<26;i++) {
        table.push(String.fromCharCode("A".charCodeAt(0)+i));
    }
    for(var i=0;i<26;i++) {
        table.push(String.fromCharCode("a".charCodeAt(0)+i));
    }
    for(var i=0;i<10;i++) {
        table.push(i.toString(10));
    }
    table.push("+");
    table.push("/");
    function b64encode(x) {
        var bits=[];
        for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
            var byte=x.charCodeAt(i);
            for(var j=7;j>=0;j--) {
                bits.push(byte&(1<<j));
            }
        }
        var output=[];
        for(var i=0;i<bits.length;i+=6) {
            var section=bits.slice(i, i+6).map(
                function(bit) { return bit?1:0; });
            var required=6-section.length;
            while(section.length<6) section.push(0);
            section=(section[0]<<5)|
                (section[1]<<4)|
                (section[2]<<3)|
                (section[3]<<2)|
                (section[4]<<1)|
                section[5];
            output.push(table[section]);
            if(required==2) {
                output.push('=');
            }else if(required==4) {
                output.push('==');
            }
        }
        output=output.join("");
        return output;
    }
    if(window.btoa) {
        b64encode=window.btoa;
    }
    return function createPixel(hexColor, opacity) {
        var colorTuple=[
            (hexColor&(0xFF<<16))>>16,
            (hexColor&(0xFF<<8))>>8,
            hexColor&0xFF,
            Math.floor(opacity*255)
        ];
        var data="P7\nWIDTH 1\nHEIGHT 1\nDEPTH 4\nMAXVAL 255\nTUPLTYPE RGB_ALPHA\nENDHDR\n";
        colorTuple.forEach(function(tupleElement) {
            data+=String.fromCharCode(tupleElement);
        });
        var base64DataURL="data:image/pam;base64,"+b64encode(data);
        return base64DataURL;
    }
})();
```

...but really, `canvas` should work fine.

Comment: Cool idea, but output doesn't seem to display for me in firefox4 or IE8... :/ "Failed to load url".

Comment: @aaaidan: Of course; PAM is fairly uncommon. It makes sense Firefox and IE don't support it.

Comment: @aaaidan: You can prove it works though by decoding the Base64 content into a `.pam` file and converting it with ImageMagick. Not that that's helpful for what the OP needed.