# Generate image in pure JS without canvas 

Tags: javascript, image, graphics, data-uri

How to generate/draw picture in pure JavaScript (no external lib) from array of pixels without canvas? I try to generate image in URI form but without success (picture format-s are not easy to fast understand and implement)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### BMP dataURI

You can generate BMP (bitmap) dataURI using below function. RAW BMP with 24-bit - 16x16 RGB is transformed to 2397 bytes dataURI (the image width should be divisable by 4).

```js
/**
 * Generate dataURI raw BMP image
 *
 * @param width - image width (num of pixels)
 * @param pixels - 1D array of RGB pixels (pixel = 3 numbers in
 *                 range 0-255; staring from left bottom corner)
 * @return dataURI string
 */
function genBMPUri(width, pixels) {
  let LE= n=> (n + 2**32).toString(16).match(/\B../g).reverse().join``;
  let wh= LE(width).slice(0,4) + LE(pixels.length/width/3).slice(0,4);
  let size= LE(26+pixels.length);

  let head=`424d${size}000000001a0000000C000000${wh}01001800`;
  
  return "data:image/bmp," + [
           ...head.match(/../g), 
           ...pixels.map(x=> x.toString(16).padStart(2,'0'))
         ].map(x=>'%'+x).join``;
}


// TEST

// 16x16 pixels - 1D Array of pixels (start from bottom-left corner) 
// where one pixel has 3 color component (each 0-255) RGB 
imgagePixels=[0,0,0,8,90,114,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,42,129,252,0,0,0,8,90,114,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,90,114,8,90,114,42,129,252,42,129,252,42,129,252,0,0,0,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,90,114,8,31,205,8,31,205,42,129,252,8,31,205,8,31,205,42,129,252,8,31,205,8,90,114,8,90,114,42,129,252,42,129,252,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,90,114,0,0,0,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,31,205,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,31,205,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,90,114,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,31,205,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,31,205,8,90,114,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,42,129,252,42,129,252,42,129,252,42,129,252,42,129,252,42,129,252,42,129,252,8,90,114,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,90,114,8,90,114,42,129,252,42,129,252,42,129,252,42,129,252,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,90,114,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,90,114,42,129,252,8,90,114,8,90,114,42,129,252,42,129,252,42,129,252,8,90,114,42,129,252,42,129,252,42,129,252,8,90,114,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,90,114,42,129,252,8,90,114,42,129,252,42,129,252,42,129,252,8,90,114,42,129,252,42,129,252,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,90,114,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,90,114,42,129,252,42,129,252,8,90,114,42,129,252,0,0,0,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,90,114,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,42,129,252,42,129,252,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,0,0,0,0,0,0,42,129,252,42,129,252,42,129,252,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,42,129,252,42,129,252,42,129,252];

uri = genBMPUri(16, imgagePixels);
msg.innerHTML+= uri;
pic.src= uri;
```

```css
img{image-rendering: pixelated;width:128px;height:128px}
pre{word-break: break-all;white-space: pre-wrap;}
```

```html
<img id="pic">
<pre id="msg">Copy below dataURI to browser url top bar or src attrib in img tag<br><br></pre>
```

Base64 encoded 24bit 16x16 RGB is transformed to 1118 bytes (~2x less than RAW)

```js
/**
 * Generate dataURI base64 BMP image
 *
 * @param width - image width (num of pixels)
 * @param pixels - 1D array of RGB pixels (pixel = 3 numbers in
 *                 range 0-255; staring from left bottom corner)
 * @return dataURI string
 */
function genBMPUri(width, pixels) {
  let LE= n=> (n + 2**32).toString(16).match(/\B../g).reverse().join``;
  let wh= LE(width).slice(0,4) + LE(pixels.length/width/3).slice(0,4);
  let size= LE(26+pixels.length);

  let head=`424d${size}000000001b0000000C000000${wh}0100180000`;
  
  return "data:image/bmp;base64,"
         + btoa(String.fromCharCode(...head.match(/../g).map(x=> +`0x${x}`))) 
         + btoa(pixels.map(p=>String.fromCharCode(p)).join``);
}


// TEST

// 16x16 pixels - 1D Array of pixels (start from bottom-left corner) 
// where one pixel has 3 color component (each 0-255) RGB 
imgagePixels=[0,0,0,8,90,114,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,42,129,252,0,0,0,8,90,114,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,90,114,8,90,114,42,129,252,42,129,252,42,129,252,0,0,0,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,90,114,8,31,205,8,31,205,42,129,252,8,31,205,8,31,205,42,129,252,8,31,205,8,90,114,8,90,114,42,129,252,42,129,252,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,90,114,0,0,0,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,31,205,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,31,205,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,90,114,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,31,205,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,31,205,8,90,114,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,42,129,252,42,129,252,42,129,252,42,129,252,42,129,252,42,129,252,42,129,252,8,90,114,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,90,114,8,90,114,42,129,252,42,129,252,42,129,252,42,129,252,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,90,114,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,90,114,42,129,252,8,90,114,8,90,114,42,129,252,42,129,252,42,129,252,8,90,114,42,129,252,42,129,252,42,129,252,8,90,114,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,90,114,42,129,252,8,90,114,42,129,252,42,129,252,42,129,252,8,90,114,42,129,252,42,129,252,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,90,114,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,90,114,42,129,252,42,129,252,8,90,114,42,129,252,0,0,0,8,90,114,8,90,114,8,90,114,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,42,129,252,42,129,252,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,8,31,205,0,0,0,0,0,0,42,129,252,42,129,252,42,129,252,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,42,129,252,42,129,252,42,129,252];

uri = genBMPUri(16, imgagePixels);
msg.innerHTML+= uri;
pic.src= uri;
```

```css
img{image-rendering: pixelated;width:128px;height:128px}
pre{word-break: break-all;white-space: pre-wrap;}
```

```html
<img id="pic">
<pre id="msg">Copy below dataURI to browser url top bar or src attrib in img tag<br><br></pre>
```

RAW Transparent BMP 32bit RGBA 16x16 (3453 bytes)

```js
/**
 * Generate dataURI raw BMP image
 *
 * @param width - image width (num of pixels)
 * @param pixels - 1D array of RGBA pixels (pixel = 4 numbers in
 *                 range 0-255; staring from left bottom corner)
 * @return dataURI string
 */
function genBMPUri(width, pixels) {
  let LE= n=> (n + 2**32).toString(16).match(/\B../g).reverse().join``;
  let wh= LE(width) + LE(pixels.length/width/4);
  let size= LE(108+pixels.length);
  let r= n=>'0'.repeat(n);
  
  let head = `424d${size}ZZ7AZ006CZ00${wh}01002Z3${r(50)}FFZFFZFFZZZFF${r(104)}`

  return "data:image/bmp," + [
            ...head.replace(/Z/g,'0000').match(/../g), 
            ...pixels.map(x=> x.toString(16).padStart(2,'0'))
         ].map(x=>'%'+x).join``;
}


// TEST
// 16x16 pixels - 1D Array of pixels (start from bottom-left corner) 
// where one pixel has 4 color component (each 0-255) RGBA 
image=[0,0,0,0,8,90,114,16,0,0,0,32,0,0,0,48,8,31,205,64,8,31,205,80,8,31,205,96,8,31,205,112,0,0,0,128,0,0,0,144,0,0,0,160,0,0,0,176,0,0,0,192,0,0,0,208,0,0,0,224,0,0,0,240,0,0,0,0,8,90,114,16,8,90,114,32,8,90,114,48,8,31,205,64,8,31,205,80,8,31,205,96,8,31,205,112,8,31,205,128,8,31,205,144,8,31,205,160,0,0,0,176,0,0,0,192,0,0,0,208,0,0,0,224,0,0,0,240,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,8,90,114,32,8,90,114,48,8,90,114,64,8,31,205,80,8,31,205,96,8,31,205,112,8,31,205,128,8,31,205,144,8,31,205,160,8,31,205,176,8,31,205,192,8,31,205,208,0,0,0,224,0,0,0,240,0,0,0,0,42,129,252,16,0,0,0,32,8,90,114,48,8,31,205,64,8,31,205,80,8,31,205,96,8,31,205,112,8,31,205,128,8,31,205,144,8,31,205,160,8,31,205,176,8,31,205,192,8,31,205,208,8,90,114,224,8,90,114,240,42,129,252,0,42,129,252,16,42,129,252,32,0,0,0,48,8,31,205,64,8,31,205,80,8,90,114,96,8,31,205,112,8,31,205,128,42,129,252,144,8,31,205,160,8,31,205,176,42,129,252,192,8,31,205,208,8,90,114,224,8,90,114,240,42,129,252,0,42,129,252,16,8,90,114,32,8,90,114,48,8,90,114,64,8,90,114,80,8,90,114,96,8,90,114,112,8,31,205,128,8,31,205,144,8,31,205,160,8,31,205,176,8,31,205,192,0,0,0,208,0,0,0,224,8,90,114,240,0,0,0,0,8,90,114,16,8,90,114,32,8,90,114,48,8,90,114,64,8,90,114,80,8,90,114,96,8,90,114,112,8,31,205,128,8,90,114,144,8,90,114,160,8,90,114,176,8,31,205,192,0,0,0,208,0,0,0,224,8,90,114,240,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,8,90,114,32,8,90,114,48,8,90,114,64,8,90,114,80,8,90,114,96,8,31,205,112,8,90,114,128,8,90,114,144,8,90,114,
160,8,31,205,176,8,90,114,192,0,0,0,208,0,0,0,224,0,0,0,240,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,0,0,0,32,0,0,0,48,0,0,0,64,0,0,0,80,42,129,252,96,42,129,252,112,42,129,252,128,42,129,252,144,42,129,252,160,42,129,252,176,42,129,252,192,8,90,114,208,0,0,0,224,0,0,0,240,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,0,0,0,32,0,0,0,48,8,90,114,64,8,90,114,80,42,129,252,96,42,129,252,112,42,129,252,128,42,129,252,144,8,90,114,160,8,90,114,176,8,90,114,192,8,90,114,208,8,90,114,224,0,0,0,240,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,0,0,0,32,0,0,0,48,8,90,114,64,42,129,252,80,8,90,114,96,8,90,114,112,42,129,252,128,42,129,252,144,42,129,252,160,8,90,114,176,42,129,252,192,42,129,252,208,42,129,252,224,8,90,114,240,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,0,0,0,32,0,0,0,48,8,90,114,64,42,129,252,80,8,90,114,96,42,129,252,112,42,129,252,128,42,129,252,144,8,90,114,160,42,129,252,176,42,129,252,192,8,90,114,208,8,90,114,224,8,90,114,240,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,0,0,0,32,0,0,0,48,0,0,0,64,8,90,114,80,8,90,114,96,8,90,114,112,42,129,252,128,42,129,252,144,8,90,114,160,42,129,252,176,0,0,0,192,8,90,114,208,8,90,114,224,8,90,114,240,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,0,0,0,32,0,0,0,48,0,0,0,64,8,31,205,80,8,31,205,96,8,31,205,112,8,31,205,128,8,31,205,144,8,31,205,160,8,31,205,176,8,31,205,192,8,31,205,208,42,129,252,224,42,129,252,240,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,0,0,0,32,0,0,0,48,0,0,0,64,0,0,0,80,8,31,205,96,8,31,205,112,8,31,205,128,8,31,205,144,8,31,205,160,0,0,0,176,0,0,0,192,42,129,252,208,42,129,252,224,42,129,252,240,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,0,0,0,32,0,0,0,48,0,0,0,64,0,0,0,80,0,0,0,96,0,0,0,112,0,0,0,128,0,0,0,144,0,0,0,160,0,0,0,176,0,0,0,192,42,129,252,208,42,129,252,224,42,129,252,240]
uri = genBMPUri(16, image);
msg.innerHTML+= uri;
pic.src= uri;
```

```css
img{position:fixed;image-rendering: pixelated;width:128px;height:128px}
pre{word-break: break-all;white-space: pre-wrap;}
```

```html
<img id="pic">
<pre id="msg"></pre>
```

Base64 Transparent BMP 32bit RGBA 16x16 (1554 bytes - ~2x less than RAW)

```js
/**
 * Generate dataURI raw BMP image
 *
 * @param width - image width (num of pixels)
 * @param pixels - 1D array of RGBA pixels (pixel = 4 numbers in
 *                 range 0-255; staring from left bottom corner)
 * @return dataURI string
 */
function genBMPUri(width, pixels) {
  let LE= n=> (n + 2**32).toString(16).match(/\B../g).reverse().join``;
  let wh= LE(width) + LE(pixels.length/width/4);
  let size= LE(109+pixels.length);
  let r= n=>'0'.repeat(n);
  
  let head = `424d${size}ZZ7BZ006CZ00${wh}01002Z3${r(50)}FFZFFZFFZZZFF${r(106)}`

  return "data:image/bmp;base64,"
    + btoa(String.fromCharCode(...head.replace(/Z/g,'0000').match(/../g).map(x=> +`0x${x}`))) 
    + btoa(pixels.map(p=>String.fromCharCode(p)).join``);
}


// TEST
// 16x16 pixels - 1D Array of pixels (start from bottom-left corner) 
// where one pixel has 4 color component (each 0-255) RGBA 
image=[0,0,0,0,8,90,114,16,0,0,0,32,0,0,0,48,8,31,205,64,8,31,205,80,8,31,205,96,8,31,205,112,0,0,0,128,0,0,0,144,0,0,0,160,0,0,0,176,0,0,0,192,0,0,0,208,0,0,0,224,0,0,0,240,0,0,0,0,8,90,114,16,8,90,114,32,8,90,114,48,8,31,205,64,8,31,205,80,8,31,205,96,8,31,205,112,8,31,205,128,8,31,205,144,8,31,205,160,0,0,0,176,0,0,0,192,0,0,0,208,0,0,0,224,0,0,0,240,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,8,90,114,32,8,90,114,48,8,90,114,64,8,31,205,80,8,31,205,96,8,31,205,112,8,31,205,128,8,31,205,144,8,31,205,160,8,31,205,176,8,31,205,192,8,31,205,208,0,0,0,224,0,0,0,240,0,0,0,0,42,129,252,16,0,0,0,32,8,90,114,48,8,31,205,64,8,31,205,80,8,31,205,96,8,31,205,112,8,31,205,128,8,31,205,144,8,31,205,160,8,31,205,176,8,31,205,192,8,31,205,208,8,90,114,224,8,90,114,240,42,129,252,0,42,129,252,16,42,129,252,32,0,0,0,48,8,31,205,64,8,31,205,80,8,90,114,96,8,31,205,112,8,31,205,128,42,129,252,144,8,31,205,160,8,31,205,176,42,129,252,192,8,31,205,208,8,90,114,224,8,90,114,240,42,129,252,0,42,129,252,16,8,90,114,32,8,90,114,48,8,90,114,64,8,90,114,80,8,90,114,96,8,90,114,112,8,31,205,128,8,31,205,144,8,31,205,160,8,31,205,176,8,31,205,192,0,0,0,208,0,0,0,224,8,90,114,240,0,0,0,0,8,90,114,16,8,90,114,32,8,90,114,48,8,90,114,64,8,90,114,80,8,90,114,96,8,90,114,112,8,31,205,128,8,90,114,144,8,90,114,160,8,90,114,176,8,31,205,192,0,0,0,208,0,0,0,224,8,90,114,240,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,8,90,114,32,8,90,114,48,8,90,114,64,8,90,114,80,8,90,114,96,8,31,205,112,8,90,114,128,8,90,114,144,8,90,114,
160,8,31,205,176,8,90,114,192,0,0,0,208,0,0,0,224,0,0,0,240,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,0,0,0,32,0,0,0,48,0,0,0,64,0,0,0,80,42,129,252,96,42,129,252,112,42,129,252,128,42,129,252,144,42,129,252,160,42,129,252,176,42,129,252,192,8,90,114,208,0,0,0,224,0,0,0,240,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,0,0,0,32,0,0,0,48,8,90,114,64,8,90,114,80,42,129,252,96,42,129,252,112,42,129,252,128,42,129,252,144,8,90,114,160,8,90,114,176,8,90,114,192,8,90,114,208,8,90,114,224,0,0,0,240,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,0,0,0,32,0,0,0,48,8,90,114,64,42,129,252,80,8,90,114,96,8,90,114,112,42,129,252,128,42,129,252,144,42,129,252,160,8,90,114,176,42,129,252,192,42,129,252,208,42,129,252,224,8,90,114,240,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,0,0,0,32,0,0,0,48,8,90,114,64,42,129,252,80,8,90,114,96,42,129,252,112,42,129,252,128,42,129,252,144,8,90,114,160,42,129,252,176,42,129,252,192,8,90,114,208,8,90,114,224,8,90,114,240,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,0,0,0,32,0,0,0,48,0,0,0,64,8,90,114,80,8,90,114,96,8,90,114,112,42,129,252,128,42,129,252,144,8,90,114,160,42,129,252,176,0,0,0,192,8,90,114,208,8,90,114,224,8,90,114,240,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,0,0,0,32,0,0,0,48,0,0,0,64,8,31,205,80,8,31,205,96,8,31,205,112,8,31,205,128,8,31,205,144,8,31,205,160,8,31,205,176,8,31,205,192,8,31,205,208,42,129,252,224,42,129,252,240,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,0,0,0,32,0,0,0,48,0,0,0,64,0,0,0,80,8,31,205,96,8,31,205,112,8,31,205,128,8,31,205,144,8,31,205,160,0,0,0,176,0,0,0,192,42,129,252,208,42,129,252,224,42,129,252,240,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,0,0,0,32,0,0,0,48,0,0,0,64,0,0,0,80,0,0,0,96,0,0,0,112,0,0,0,128,0,0,0,144,0,0,0,160,0,0,0,176,0,0,0,192,42,129,252,208,42,129,252,224,42,129,252,240]
uri = genBMPUri(16, image);
msg.innerHTML+= uri;
pic.src= uri;
```

```css
img{position:fixed;image-rendering: pixelated;width:128px;height:128px}
pre{word-break: break-all;white-space: pre-wrap;}
```

```html
<img id="pic">
<pre id="msg"></pre>
```

### BONUS

- You cannot use notation `String.fromCharCode(...array)` with big arrays (e.g. 256*256*4) this will throw exception (you need to made conversion one-by one like in base64 snippet above).
- Details for [BMP header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) of example picture (+ [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) procedure which came from [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/193794/88163))

  ```js
                            // hex values, offsets and sizes in little endian
  head = [                  // header (before 16x16 RGBA(32bit) pixels  = 1024 bytes raw pixels data)
    "42", "4d",             // "BM" bitmap signature
    "1a", "04", "00", "00", // 0x41a = 1050dec = 16*16*4+26 bytes, total size of header and pixels 
    "00", "00", "00", "00", // reserved
    "1a", "00", "00", "00", // 0x1a=26 bytes, header size (pixels raw data start offset)
    "0C", "00", "00", "00", // 0x0C=12 bytes, Size of DIB header (type signature) - here:  BITMAPCOREHEADER
    "10", "00",             // 0x10=16 pixel, width  INT (little endian)
    "10", "00",             // 0x10=16 pixel, height INT (little endian)
    "01", "00",             // reserved
    "18", "00",             // bit per pixel 0x18=24 (1,4,8,16=0x10,24=0x18,32=0x20)
  ];

  // Conversion to little endian example (padding to 32bit)
  // 0x45678 -> 0x00045678 -> 0x78560400
  LE = (0x45678 + 2**32).toString(16).match(/\B../g).reverse().join``;
  console.log(LE);
  ```
- details of transparent BMP header

  ```js
  bmpHeaderHex = [
  "42", "4d",                  // "BM"
  "6c","04","00","00", // 0x46c=1132 size of file in bytes
  "00","00","00","00", // reserved
  "7a","00","00","00", // 0x7a=122 bitmap raw data start offset (can be changed)
  //DIB header
  "6c","00","00","00", // 0x6C=108 header size/sign BITMAPV4HEADER
  "10","00","00","00", // 0x10=16 pixel width  INT
  "10","00","00","00", // 0x10=16 pixel height  INT
  "01","00",           // reserved
  "20","00",           // 0x20=32 bit per pixel

  "03","00","00","00", // BI_BITFIELDS, no pixel array compression used
  "00","00","00","00", // Size of the raw bitmap data (including padding)
  "00","00","00","00", // width ppm
  "00","00","00","00", // height ppm
  "00","00","00","00", // colors in palette
  "00","00","00","00", // important colors

  "00","00","FF","00", // red channel bit mask
  "00","FF","00","00", // green channel bit mask
  "FF","00","00","00", // blue channel bit mask
  "00","00","00","FF", // alpha channel bit mask
  "20","6E","69","57", // little-endian 'Win '

  "00","00","00","00", // unused 
  "00","00","00","00", // unused 
  "00","00","00","00", // unused 
  "00","00","00","00", // unused 
  "00","00","00","00", // unused 
  "00","00","00","00", // unused 
  "00","00","00","00", // unused 
  "00","00","00","00", // unused 
  "00","00","00","00", // unused 

  "00","00","00","00", // 0 Red Gamma
  "00","00","00","00", // 0 Green Gamma
  "00","00","00","00", // 0 Blue Gamma
  ];
  ```
- example code-golf fractal (after ~5s generation you can click rmb on picture, copy its adress and paste in browser adress bar)

  ```js
  c=512;for(p=i='';j=x=y=0,++i<=c*c;p+=9*c+9*j)while(x*x+y*y<4&&++j-c)[x,y]=[x*x-y*y+i%c/128-2,2*x*y+i/c/128-2]
  document.write(`<img src=data:image/bmp;base64,Qk0bAAwAAAAAABsAAAAMAAAAAAIAAgEAGAAA${p}>`)
  ```

Comment: how are you both asking and answering the question ? :D

Comment: Cheers! And thanks for sharing too. It is quite a useful snippet

Comment: Why not use typed arrays? Should make dealing with endianness and byte data much easier.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work with a single, red pixel. I tried `genBMPUri(1, [255, 0, 0])`. Can you show that usage too?

Comment: @styfle you are right - there is some problem with rgb. When I will have more time I will inwestigate this case. However as workaround you can use rgba (transparent) version `genBMPUri(1, [0,0,255,255]);` to get 1 red pixel bitmap

Comment: Still didn't work for me. Although svg worked from this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11293812/266535

Comment: @styfle I check it twice - for rgba 1 pixel works (RAW and base64) and gives `data:image/bmp;base64,Qk1xAAAAAAAAAHsAAABsAAAAAQAAAAEAAAABACAAAwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/AAD/AAD/AAAAAAAA/wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD//w==`

Comment: This other answer using gif seems to produce smaller URIs https://stackoverflow.com/a/33919020/266535

Comment: @styfle this answer is not for question for which you give link in your previous comment.

Comment: how do I have separate width and height IE 1920 by 1080 [assuming my pixel array is 1d]?

Comment: @Yeets by `genBMPUri(1920, imgagePixels)` (height will be calulated automatically using width an array length)

Answer (score 1):

You can draw picture on screen from array using div-s

```js
function draw(image) {
  let s=''
  let zoom=8;
  for(let i=0; i<16; i++) for(let j=0; j<16; j++) {
    let k=4*((15-i)*16+j);
    let c=`rgba(${image[k+2]},${image[k+1]},${image[k]},${image[k+3]/255})`
    s+=`<div style="background: ${c}; width:${zoom}px; height:${zoom}px"></div>`
  }

  pic.style.width = `${16*zoom}px`;
  pic.innerHTML = s;
}

image=[0,0,0,0,8,90,114,16,0,0,0,32,0,0,0,48,8,31,205,64,8,31,205,80,8,31,205,96,8,31,205,112,0,0,0,128,0,0,0,144,0,0,0,160,0,0,0,176,0,0,0,192,0,0,0,208,0,0,0,224,0,0,0,240,0,0,0,0,8,90,114,16,8,90,114,32,8,90,114,48,8,31,205,64,8,31,205,80,8,31,205,96,8,31,205,112,8,31,205,128,8,31,205,144,8,31,205,160,0,0,0,176,0,0,0,192,0,0,0,208,0,0,0,224,0,0,0,240,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,8,90,114,32,8,90,114,48,8,90,114,64,8,31,205,80,8,31,205,96,8,31,205,112,8,31,205,128,8,31,205,144,8,31,205,160,8,31,205,176,8,31,205,192,8,31,205,208,0,0,0,224,0,0,0,240,0,0,0,0,42,129,252,16,0,0,0,32,8,90,114,48,8,31,205,64,8,31,205,80,8,31,205,96,8,31,205,112,8,31,205,128,8,31,205,144,8,31,205,160,8,31,205,176,8,31,205,192,8,31,205,208,8,90,114,224,8,90,114,240,42,129,252,0,42,129,252,16,42,129,252,32,0,0,0,48,8,31,205,64,8,31,205,80,8,90,114,96,8,31,205,112,8,31,205,128,42,129,252,144,8,31,205,160,8,31,205,176,42,129,252,192,8,31,205,208,8,90,114,224,8,90,114,240,42,129,252,0,42,129,252,16,8,90,114,32,8,90,114,48,8,90,114,64,8,90,114,80,8,90,114,96,8,90,114,112,8,31,205,128,8,31,205,144,8,31,205,160,8,31,205,176,8,31,205,192,0,0,0,208,0,0,0,224,8,90,114,240,0,0,0,0,8,90,114,16,8,90,114,32,8,90,114,48,8,90,114,64,8,90,114,80,8,90,114,96,8,90,114,112,8,31,205,128,8,90,114,144,8,90,114,160,8,90,114,176,8,31,205,192,0,0,0,208,0,0,0,224,8,90,114,240,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,8,90,114,32,8,90,114,48,8,90,114,64,8,90,114,80,8,90,114,96,8,31,205,112,8,90,114,128,8,90,114,144,8,90,114,
160,8,31,205,176,8,90,114,192,0,0,0,208,0,0,0,224,0,0,0,240,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,0,0,0,32,0,0,0,48,0,0,0,64,0,0,0,80,42,129,252,96,42,129,252,112,42,129,252,128,42,129,252,144,42,129,252,160,42,129,252,176,42,129,252,192,8,90,114,208,0,0,0,224,0,0,0,240,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,0,0,0,32,0,0,0,48,8,90,114,64,8,90,114,80,42,129,252,96,42,129,252,112,42,129,252,128,42,129,252,144,8,90,114,160,8,90,114,176,8,90,114,192,8,90,114,208,8,90,114,224,0,0,0,240,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,0,0,0,32,0,0,0,48,8,90,114,64,42,129,252,80,8,90,114,96,8,90,114,112,42,129,252,128,42,129,252,144,42,129,252,160,8,90,114,176,42,129,252,192,42,129,252,208,42,129,252,224,8,90,114,240,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,0,0,0,32,0,0,0,48,8,90,114,64,42,129,252,80,8,90,114,96,42,129,252,112,42,129,252,128,42,129,252,144,8,90,114,160,42,129,252,176,42,129,252,192,8,90,114,208,8,90,114,224,8,90,114,240,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,0,0,0,32,0,0,0,48,0,0,0,64,8,90,114,80,8,90,114,96,8,90,114,112,42,129,252,128,42,129,252,144,8,90,114,160,42,129,252,176,0,0,0,192,8,90,114,208,8,90,114,224,8,90,114,240,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,0,0,0,32,0,0,0,48,0,0,0,64,8,31,205,80,8,31,205,96,8,31,205,112,8,31,205,128,8,31,205,144,8,31,205,160,8,31,205,176,8,31,205,192,8,31,205,208,42,129,252,224,42,129,252,240,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,0,0,0,32,0,0,0,48,0,0,0,64,0,0,0,80,8,31,205,96,8,31,205,112,8,31,205,128,8,31,205,144,8,31,205,160,0,0,0,176,0,0,0,192,42,129,252,208,42,129,252,224,42,129,252,240,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,0,0,0,32,0,0,0,48,0,0,0,64,0,0,0,80,0,0,0,96,0,0,0,112,0,0,0,128,0,0,0,144,0,0,0,160,0,0,0,176,0,0,0,192,42,129,252,208,42,129,252,224,42,129,252,240];

draw(image);
```

```css
#pic {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="pic"></div>
```

Comment: interesting, how do I have seprarte width and height? is j the same as width here?

Comment: this is 1D array witch 2D data - all picture lines are saved one by one on this 1D array

Comment: but how do I specify a diffferent height and width? like 1920 by 1080? is it possible with this method